# JS, dynamically created table with coordinates

Tags: javascript

I want to create a table where each cell will have data-attribute of `x` and `y`, in a sort of Cartesian manner: `x` should be incremented by rows and `y` by cells. The problem is that the only implementation I could come up with is where I create rows first and then insert cells per row. It does work with `y` since I can just increment it with the each created cell and it will be always 1 through 10. But it doesn't work at all with `x`. I've tried creating additional loops inside loops, but it didn't quite work out. Should I rewrite logic completely, or there's another way?
Thanks!

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(let key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

const rows = 10;
const columns = 10;
const table = document.getElementById('table');

function initBoard() {

 for (let i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   const row = document.createElement('tr');

   for (let k = columns - 1, x = 1, y = 1; k >= 0; k--) {
     let cell = document.createElement('td');
                                  // ↓ Should be another way
     setAttributes(cell, { 'data-x': x++, 'data-y': y++ });
     row.appendChild(cell)
   };

   table.appendChild(row)
 };
}

window.onload = initBoard();
```

[JSfiddle with above code](https://jsfiddle.net/rm0sxznh/)

Comment: Put `x=1` to outer loop definition and put `x++` after `i--`, with a comma maybe

Comment: @SergeSeredenko wow, I feel really silly. Thanks!